# InputBindings for Page in Style and add Key Binding

Tags: wpf, mvvm, styles, key-bindings

**I have many identical pages of the following kind:**

```
<Page x:Class="DP.View.DepartmentsView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Style="{StaticResource PageC}">
<!--<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="F" Command="{Binding FindCommand}" CommandParameter=""/>
    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="P" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DG}"/>
</Page.InputBindings>-->
<Grid Background="LightGray">
    <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridC}" x:Name="DG"/>
</Grid>
```

And I want to bind `KeyBinding` in style.

**What's wrong with the style?:**

```
<Style x:Key="PageC" TargetType="Page" >
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
            <Page>
                <Page.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="F" Command="{Binding FindCommand}" CommandParameter=""/>
                    <KeyBinding Modifiers="Ctrl" Key="P" Command="{Binding PrintCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DG}"/>
                </Page.InputBindings>
            </Page>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: I figured it out. In the ControlTemplate, you must specify a structure (for example, Grid), and specify the context in the design